# DB query to get time blocks with highest-priority user

Tags: php, database, loops

For my service, I have a table that shows who used it during which time. It includes the columns

```
customer | start_date  | end_date | priority
```

`priority` can be Low, Medium or High.

For example, the customers `husband` and `wife` uses services with above priorities in a month.

Husband and wife uses services like below

```
customer     start_date end_date    priority
-----------------------------------------------
Husband      2019-11-01 2019-11-04  High   
Husband      2019-11-05 2019-11-20  Low
Husband      2019-11-21 2019-11-30  Medium
Wife         2019-11-01 2019-11-06  Medium
Wife         2019-11-07 2019-11-25  High
Wife         2019-11-26 2019-11-30  Low
```

So at end of the month for each time span I have to derive whoever uses highest proprieties between that dates, so for example:

```
customer       start_date end_date      priority
----------------------------------------------
Husband        2019-11-01 2019-11-04    High    (priority value from husband)
Wife           2019-11-05 2019-11-06    Medium  (priority value from wife)
Wife           2019-11-07 2019-11-25    High    (priority value from wife)
Husband        2019-11-26 2019-11-30    Medium   (priority value from husband)
```

How to do this with PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a database involved? Your question is unclear and too broad.

Comment: No clue what is meant. Please be more specific

Comment: _“Please provide me some valuable suggestions on this. How to do this with PHP”_ - if you do not even have any approach yourself at all, then I’d say this is simply way too broad of a question. Same as with this not being a code writing service, this is not a place where you can simply “outsource” your complete job of developing such an algorithm to either.

Comment: Folks, I understand that this isn't the first question that does not show any research, but please keep in mind that this user is a newcomer and does not have your experience on the site. user3049475, they are right though that if you post here it is expected that you show your progress up to now, because that makes it much easier for everyone to start working on your problem without wasting time. I'd recommend you read through the guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to write a [mcve]. Then you can [edit] this question and I'm sure there will be a solution

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry for unclear question. First set of records(6 records) coming from database. I have to derive 2nd set of records(4 records) through some code logic. I'm not getting any ideas on how to do this. Expecting some help or suggestions.

Comment: @akraf I would agree with you, but they have been here for "Member for 5 years, 11 months". So, they are not new to asking questions or to how things work here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner oh, I see now, that's true...

Comment: @RussJ Really i'm not getting ideas on at least how to achieve this and i'm the only developer in my company. So i'm expecting some help from SOF members.

Comment: @user3049475 Seeing this is database-related, have you tried using a WHERE clause along with COUNT(column_name)? I think that that is what you're asking about. Which RDBMS are you using, mysql? mssql? other?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner From one parent table i'm getting first set of records. So my logic should derive second set of records and insert them into new table.

Comment: Please check my edit if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you are trying to extract time spans from your data from when to when a service was used by whom with which priority.

I would suggest that you change your data structure to make it easier for you:

- Create a table (e.g. called `usageperday`) with the columns
  `customer  | date | priority`

  You should write `priority` as an integer, `1 = low, 2 = medium, 3 = high`
- Fill that table using your input data. For example, for

  ```
  Husband      2019-11-01 2019-11-04  High
  Wife         2019-11-01 2019-11-06  Medium
  ```

  you write into the table:

  ```
  Husband   2019-11-01  3
  Husband   2019-11-02  3
   ...
  Husband   2019-11-04  3
  Wife      2019-11-01  2
  Wife      2019-11-02  2
   ...
  Wife      2019-11-06  2
  ```

  ... and so on for every row in your input
- Then, for each day, you select from the table the customer with the highest priority, so using something like this SQL

  ```
  SELECT customer
  FROM usageperday
  WHERE priority = max(priority)
  GROUP BY date;
  ```
- Finally, you can summarise that list of days into one row for each contiguous time
  block, like described [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934930/sql-server-contiguous-dates-summarizing-multiple-rows-into-contiguous-start-an)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. Below is the logic

```
husbandlevels = getPrioritiesBYPid(husband);

wifelevels = getPrioritiesBYPid(wife)

FirstLevel = "";

FirstDate = '';

Loop through the days of the month {

               FirstDate = ( FirstDate == '' ) ? TodayDate : FirstDate;

               husbandLevel = getPriority(TodayDate,husbandlevels);

               wifeLevel = getPriority(TodayDate,wifelevels);

               FortodayLevel = (husbandLevel > wifeLevel ) ? 1 : 2;

               if ( FortodayLevel != FirstLevel || FirstLevel != '' ) {

                              // Insert in the table

                              -- FirstDate,TodayDate - 1,FirstLevel

                              FirstLevel = FortodayLevel;

                              FirstDate = TodayDate;

               }

}
```